# Get the parent xml node based on an inner node's value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xpath, xquery-sql

```
declare @xmlVal xml
set @xmlVal = 
'<user>
    <token><id>ABC123</id><endDate>2013-06-16 18:48:50.111</endDate></token>
    <token><id>XYX456</id><endDate>2014-01-01 18:48:50.111</endDate></token>
</user>'
```

I need  the entire token node as xml where id=ABC123 so the out put will be :

```
<token>
    <id>ABC123</id>
    <endDate>2013-06-16 18:48:50.111</endDate>
</token>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  
a.b.value('id[1]','nvarchar(max)') id,
a.b.value('endDate[1]','datetime') endDate
 FROM    @xmlval.nodes('//user/token[id="ABC123"]') a(b)
 FOR XML PATH('token')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select @xmlVal.query('/user/token[id="ABC123"]')
```